# Selecting a row with the same ID when the values of the second column are known

Tags: mysql

He's a beginner, and I've encountered this programming conundrum:

We have sample records in the table:

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 |

I would like to retrieve records with VALUE (3,4) values with the same ID, so as a result I would like to get ID 2

How to write such a mysql query to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HAVING`.

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE value IN (3, 4) GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

I have prepared an [example](https://rextester.com/JRCF53438) for you to see how you work.